# Set UIWebView Address String

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, uiwebview

Declared Function

```
- (IBAction) changeProductWeb:(NSString *)str;


- (IBAction) changeProductWeb:(NSString *)str{

    NSString *urlAddress = str;
    NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlAddress];


    [webView loadRequest:request];

}
```

Set string using Array

```
[cell changeProductWeb:[webTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

The Array

```
webTitle = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:

            @"bar.html",
            @"bar.html",
            @"bar.html",
            @"bar.html",

            nil];
```

When I launches it chrashes, if  I set the string staticaly in the:

```
- (IBAction) changeProductWeb:(NSString *)str{
```

It works fine

Comment: What is the scope of the array? is it retained?

Answer (score 0):

`[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:]` wants an NSURL, not an NSString. Try something like this instead:

```
    NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]];
```

Comment: [cell changeProductWeb:[webTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

SIGBARTs Here

Comment: @Rollo: Are you sure `indexPath.row` is less than `webTitle.count`?

Comment: @Rollo: There's your problem then. For example, if `webTitle.count` returns 4 then indexes 0, 1, 2, and 3 are valid. Index 4 is out of bounds and will throw an exception.

Comment: Added more objects to the array and no avial

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it works fine setting it statically because you are passing the incorrect type to [`NSURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html). `requestWithURL:` requires an [`NSURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) not an `NSString`.

```
NSURL *urlAddress = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlAddress];
```